# In catch box display my own message

Tags: asp.net-mvc

this is my `catch(exception ex){MessageBox.Show("My Own Message")}`

How to Display my own message in Asp.net MVC Controller .
 If any other way to display message Please reply

Comment: `MessageBox` is WinForms, not MVC.

Comment: You'll need to send your error message to the client , and display it there. Your code as written would attempt to display it on a window station on the server, which may or (more likely) may not be visible to an operator

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can't use `MessageBox.Show()` in a web application.  For a web application, you essentially include the message in the response (in the page) and style/render it on the page however you like.

For example, if you just want to send a "message" from the controller to the view, you can set that as a property on the model:

```
someModel.SomeProperty = "Some Message";
```

or, at worst, as part of something like `ViewData`:

```
ViewData["SomeProperty"] = "Some Message";
```

Then, in the view, you'd display it.  For example, include it somewhere in the markup:

```
@if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.SomeProperty)) {
    <div id="message">@Model.SomeProperty</div>
}
```

Then you can apply any styling or effects you want to that `div` (or to whatever markup you use there).  You can also include the message in JavaScript code, in case you want to use that to display it.  For example, if you wanted a simple `alert()`:

```
@if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.SomeProperty)) {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('@Model.SomeProperty');
    </script>
}
```

(You may need to use `<text></text>` tags judiciously when putting JavaScript code in Razor blocks.  Sometimes the syntax confuses the rendering engine.)